# Spring boot testing delete method always fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have table of users as shown:

[image]

Rest controller method for delete user is:

```
@RequestMapping(APP_USER_API_PATH)
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppUserControllerImpl implements AppUserController {

    @NonNull
    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    @NonNull
    private final AppUserMapper appUserMapper;

    @Override
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if(appUserService.findById(id).isEmpty())
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("Record not found with id = %s", id));

        // If Found then
        appUserService.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                String.format("Record with id = %s deleted", id)
        );

    }

}
```

Test class and method is as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AppUserControllerImplTest {
    private static final String ENDPOINT_URL = APP_USER_API_PATH;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppUserControllerImpl appuserController;
    @Mock
    private AppUserService appuserService;
    @Mock
    private AppUserMapper appuserMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.appuserController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void delete() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(appuserService).deleteById(ArgumentMatchers.anyLong());
        mockMvc.perform(
                        MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete(ENDPOINT_URL + "/" + 1L + ""))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        Mockito.verify(appuserService, Mockito.times(1)).deleteById(Mockito.anyLong());
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(appuserService);
    }
}
```

it always throws exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Record not found with id = 1
```

and the test always fails even if record with id = 1 exists.

Full StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Record not found with id = 1

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
    at pk.team.inlab.web.app.profile2.controller.impl.AppUserControllerImplTest.delete(AppUserControllerImplTest.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Record not found with id = 1
    at pk.team.inlab.web.app.profile2.controller.impl.AppUserControllerImpl.delete(AppUserControllerImpl.java:89)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: `AppUserService` is a mock and you are not telling it what to do on `appUserService.findById(id)`

Comment: I have this `@Mock
    private AppUserService appuserService;` is it not mocking `AppUserService`? please.

Comment: It does, but it does not know what to do when you call `appUserService.findById(id)`

Comment: Any solutions please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening because you have not mocked the findById method of AppUserService class

You have written the following piece of code

```
if(appUserService.findById(id).isEmpty()) throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("Record not found with id = %s", id));
```

which throws as exception if the item with this id is not found.

In the test class, you have mocked the AppUserService using

```
@Mock
private AppUserService appuserService;
```

however, you have not told the Mock framework what to do when the findById method is called.
Add a Mockito.when statement to your test case for example in the following format

```
Mockito.when(appUserService.findById(ArgumentMatchers.anyLong())).thenReturn("***Return a dummy object here ***")
```

This should let the mock framework know that it should return the dummy result when this method is called and that should prevent the exception from being thrown.